# char array wont print in C unless previously printed

Tags: c

So this is strange- below is my code to create a tokenizer object and the main method:

```
struct TokenizerT_ {
    char * sep;
    char * toks;
};

TokenizerT *TKCreate(char *separators, char *ts) {

    if (ts==NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }

    int lin = (int) strlen(separators);
    char yr[lin];
    yr[0] = *separators;
    int lim = 1;
    int h = 1; 

    for(h=1; h<strlen(separators); h++){
        char tmp = *(separators+h);
        int z=0;

        for (z=0; z<lim; z++) {
            if (tmp==yr[z]) {
                z=-1;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(z>-1){
            yr[h] = tmp;
            lim++;
        }

    }
    TokenizerT inu = {yr, ts};
    printf("%s\n", inu.sep);
    return &inu;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    char * arr = argv[1];
    char * y = argv[2];
    TokenizerT jer = *TKCreate(arr, y);

    printf("%s\n", jer.sep);
    printf("%s\n", jer.toks);
    return 0;
}
```

If I run the program with arguments "tes" and "testing", I get the following results:
tes
tes
testing

However, if I run the program with the printf statement in TKCreate commented out, I get:

testing.

The printf("%s\n", jer.sep) stops working and I've done nothing to the code except commenting out that printf statement in TKCreate. Why is that happening?

Comment: `inu` is local variable. It can not be used after it is out of scope.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY so how do I fix that?

Comment: use `malloc` to allocate,.

Comment: In `TKCreate` you are returning a pointer to the local variable `inu` which trashed as soon as you return from `TkCreate`. And `inu` itself contains pointer to another local variable (yr) which will also be trashed upon return from the function.

In summary : never return a pointer to a local variable that is non static.

Comment: return a copy instead of a pointer:  TokenizerT TKCreate(char *separators, char *ts) { ... return inu; }

Comment: @MichaelWalz so what do you recommend I write instead?

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of problems here:

1. `inu` is a local variable. You return the address of it. When you attempt to read from that address in `main`, you are accessing a variable that is no longer in scope. That is undefined behaviour.
2. The `sep` field of `inu` is assigned `yr`. Now, `yr` is a local variable, a character array, which decays to a pointer. Again, accessing that once the function has returned means accessing a variable whose scope has ended. Again, undefined behaviour.
3. You are using a variable length array, a VLA. I suspect that is not intentional. Generally speaking, VLAs are advanced features that should only be used when you are clear on the implications.

I suggest the following changes:

- Allocate the character arrays dynamically using `malloc`.
- Return the struct by value.

On top of that I suspect that you have other problems. It appears to me that `yr` is not null-terminated, and some elements may not be initialized at all. Is that intentional? Perhaps you actually meant to initialise `yr` to be equal to `separators` when you wrote `yr[0] = *separators`. Note that your code simply assigns a single character. To allocate `yr` dynamically, and initialise it to be equal to `separators` you can write:

```
yr := malloc(strlen(separators)+1);
strcpy(yr, separators);
```

Why do you call `strlen(separators)` multiple times? You appear to call it `1+strlen(separators)` times. You should call it once only.

Comment: I've had only three classes in C and zero involving allocating memory. I'm doing the best that I can with as little as I know.

Answer (score 2):

In C you can never return a pointer to a local function variable. Well, you can, but it won't work. Even if it *seems* to work, it is only waiting for a good opportunity to not work.

So you absolutely cannot do this:

```
TokenizerT inu = {yr, ts};
return &inu;
```

What you need to do is either pass in a pointer to the object you want to build, or use `malloc` to allocate a new one. If you use `malloc` you will need to remember to `free` the object later. And because of Windows and its multiple C runtimes it is a very good idea to `free` your objects inside a function just for that. Because if you were to have the code in a library, and `malloc` in the Debug runtime and `free` in the Release runtime, bad things happen.

So for the malloc example:

```
struct box* create_box(int x, int y) {
    struct box* b = malloc(sizeof(*b));
    if(!b) abort();
    b->x = x;
    b->y = y;
    return b;
}

void destroy_box(struct box* x) {
    free(x);
}
```

And for passing an object in:

```
void init_box(struct box* b, int x, int y) {
    b->x = x;
    b->y = y;
}

void f() {
    struct box b;
    init_box(&b, 10, 20);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to *allocate* memory for an object that is to be returned from a function. This puts the object on the *heap* (permanent memory) vice on the *stack* (memory that is recycled by the program as soon as the current function ends).

You can do that by making these changes in your TKCreate function:

```
TokenizerT *TKCreate(char *separators, char *ts) {
    ...
    # change 'char yr[lin];' to:
    char* yr = (char*)malloc(lin * sizeof(char));

    ....
    TokenizerT* inu = (TokenizerT*)malloc(sizeof(TokenizerT));
    inu->sep = yr;
    int->yoks = ts;
    printf("%s\n", inu->sep);
    return inu;
}
```

You can also clean up your main() function by only sharing one copy of the object. You could call free() on any allocate memory once you are done with it:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char * arr = argv[1];
    char * y = argv[2];
    TokenizerT jer* = TKCreate(arr, y);

    printf("%s\n", jer->sep);
    printf("%s\n", jer->toks);
    free(jer);
    return 0;
}
```